# throw error if same account number exceeds amount of 25000..otherwise insert it in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    $dupesql = "select t_id,sum(amount) as amounts from transfer WHERE acc_no='$acc_no1' AND agent_id='$agent_id' group by acc_no having sum(amount) < 25000";

    $duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

   if (mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0) {
       $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transfer`(`t_id`, `agent_id`, `agent_name`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `tname`, `tphone`, `temail`, `acc_no`, `bank`, `branch`, `code`, `amount`, `comment`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$agent_id','$agent_name','$date','$name','$phone','$email','$tname','$tphone','$temail','$accno','$bank','$branch','$code','$amt','$cmmnt','$status')");        
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Your Order has been Received \n You will be Notified via SMS/Email when the money is Transfered");window.location="../my.php"</script>';     
    }
    else{
       echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Your Account has been Used more than the limit i.e 5 Times!!!\n Please Contact !!!");window.location="../my.php"</script>'; 
    }
```

Comment: My problem is that it if the user enters the account number....& amount in the form...!!
its should check the Account number & sum(amount) i.e amount the account number has been paid & its should compare that total amount with 25000...if it's less than 25000 it should allow user to add amount..!!
if it's more than 25000 its should throw error...!!!!

Comment: for example: the account_no: 12458521544 has paid thrice amount which 1st day: 10000, 2nd day: 4000, 3rd day: 70000. so the total amount he has paid is 21000 so it should allow user to pay only 4000 so that the total will be 25000..!!

Comment: but if the user had already cross total limit of 25000 so it should not allow him to insert it should throw error..!!!!

Comment: anybody knows the solution???

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky do you have any solution??